# Calculating total number of days based on the relative date range filter in tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have a date column using which I created a "relative date" filter as follows:

[image]

Now I want to create a measure as follows:

```
SUM(value from another column)/total number of day in that date range.
```

Can someone help me how to create this measure?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you Record Date field is at the day level of detail, you could do:

```
SUM(value from another column)/countd(record_date)
```

Comment: What do you mean day level of detail? Record date field is like 6/1/2017, 6/2/2017 etc.

Comment: @Anjali In your date field if you right click on it, you can set the granularity. So is that date a week/month/day etc. If you want to count the number of days, you must set the field so that it is at the day level